# Escaping ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, escaping, advanced-custom-fields

My theme has been soft rejected many times in Themeforest for this reason.

"" 
1. Data Validation issues have been found in your theme. All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered.

Please perform a global search for "echo $" and you will see several issues.
You need to escape the variable for this field. http://envato.d.pr/zpIy/480pfq95

""

I dont what to escape here anymore, there is only one echo, but this time envato reviewer send me the example below with the field from the acf, should be ACF escaped? If yes how it should be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPWEG.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they mean check the option variable is set?

```
    $footer_copyright = get_field('footer_copyright', 'options');
    if( $footer_copyright ) {
        echo esc_html($footer_copyright);
    }
```

Comment: I dont think so, the main reason is about escaping the values(securing them)

Comment: `<?php echo esc_attr(date("Y")); ?> © 
<?php 
$it_footer_copyright = get_field("footer_copyright","options"); 

if($it_footer_copyright){
echo esc_attr($it_footer_copyright);
}
?>`

Now it looks like this, thank you alot mate hope it will be accepted this time :)

Comment: Getting even a soft reject on TF is very hard, so it sounds like you have won the hardest part of the battle. As the saying goes, good luck with sales!

Comment: Yeah hope they it will be on Themforest, thanks again :)